# Xamarin The property 'Content' is set more than once

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to make a custom header, so I created this stacklayout:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" Source="Logo.png"/>
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" Source="Title_Dark.png"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Now I want to put it above the following code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMain" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#212121" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="#E3E3E3" />
                        <Grid x:Name="GridMain">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" x:Name="Row0_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="180" x:Name="Row1_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="180" x:Name="Row2_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" x:Name="Row3_Height"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" x:Name="Column0_Width" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="Column1_Width" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" x:Name="Column2_Width" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Creator}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Body" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Image Source="VoteUp.png" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgVoteUp_Clicked" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="VoteDown.png" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgVoteDown_Clicked" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
                            <Image Source="Favorite.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgFavorite_Clicked" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="Send_Dark.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Image Source="Save_Dark.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

But when I put it right under the `<ContentPage.Content>` tag, it gives the following error:

> The property 'Content' is set more than once

When I put it above the `<ContentPage.Content>` tag, my whole screen is the header.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content` can only have **ONE** child element.  If you want to have multiple child elements, you need to place them inside of a layout container (`Grid`, `StackLayout`, etc)

Comment: And remove the whole `<ContentPage.Content>` tag?

Comment: Aaaah, I get it. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks again XD